# payment details are not inserted in database

Tags: php, paypal, utf-8

i have a problem in storing payment details in my database after make a payment through paypal. here is the coding for payment success. it takes the value but the value is not stored in database. I use tmno as userID

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'con.php';

$cartID = $_SESSION['cartID'];
$amount = $_GET['amt'];
$currency = $_GET['cc'];
$transactionID = $_GET['tx'];
$payment_status = $_GET['st'];
$invoice = mt_rand();

$tmno = $_SESSION['tmno'];

$insert_payment = "INSERT INTO payment (paymentID,cartID) VALUES
('$transactionID','$cartID')";
$result_payment=mysqli_query($con,$insert_payment);

if($result_payment){
    $update_query = "UPDATE cart SET status=1 WHERE cartID='$cartID' ";
    $update_result = mysqli_query($con,$update_query);

    if($update_result){
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE tmno='$tmno' AND status=0 ";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)>0){
            $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
            $cartID = $row1['cartID'];
        }

        else{ //if user doesn't have cart yet
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO cart(tmno) VALUES ('$tmno') ";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
            $cartID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
        }

        $_SESSION['cartID'] = $cartID;

        echo "Your payment was successfully recorded!";
        echo "<a href='UserFee.php'><h3>Click here to go back to the homepage!</h3></a>";
    } else {
        echo "Oh no!";
    }
}else {
    echo "Failed!";
}

?>
```

this is the configure.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('DB_HOST', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_NAME') or die('Error Connect to DB');
mysqli_query($con,'utf-8');
?>
```

the error shown is

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'utf-8' at line 1' in /home/sptlabua/public_html/configure.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /home/sptlabua/public_html/configure.php(3): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'utf-8') #1 /home/sptlabua/public_html/payment_success.php(5): include('/home/sptlabua/...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/sptlabua/public_html/configure.php on line 3

Comment: So what does happen? Do you get your messages "Oh no"? What details do you get from `mysql_error()`?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should use [PDO](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) or [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to help prevent such attacks.

Comment: thanks for your help. i already solve it. The problem is actually comes from the database.it does not take the value of cartID because of unique constrain in it.